# jquery ui tabs and huge buttons problem

Tags: jquery, html

In my page i got 3 divs `[A] [B] [C]` one next to each other
[A] and [C] contain jquery ui tabs.

Now the middle div [B] contains a mapviewer instance. In order to match the side divs style i created an empty tab (with no tabs) and added my mapviewer tools as button masked a hrefs on the tab header.

the jquery

```
$("#maptabs").tabs();
$("#zoomin").button();
$("#zoomout").button();
$("#repeat0").button();
$("#repeat1").button();
$("#boxzoom").button();
```

and the html:

```
<div class="maptab">
<div id="maptabs">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="tls">
        <a href="#" id= "zoomin" onclick= "zoomIn();" >+</a>
        <a href="#" id= "zoomout" onclick= "zoomOut();" >-</a>
        <a href="#" id= "boxzoom" onclick= "boxzoomin();" >[]</a>
        <a href="#" id="repeat0" name="repeat">VIEW</a>
        <a href="#" id="repeat1" name="repeat" onclick="gotoADE();">EDIT</a>
</div></li>
            </ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="mapAll">
        <div id="mapJ"></div>
        <div id="mouse_location" ></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

now the problem is that those masked a hrefs come out as extremely huge buttons 80x40 pixel big. does anyone knows why? and if making a tab ui with buttons instead of tabs on its header is a stupid idea or not.

the reason I did not put normal buttons is that the page for some reason reloads when each tool is activated

Comment: why do you need to change tab links to button? tabs already styled link (title) like a button.

Comment: iam not changing them to buttons [A] and [C] contain normal tabs while [B] is just a map with its tools ...iam making the tool buttons to look like tabs to match the style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/oface4/edit

Just add these CSS rules to your code

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li a {
   padding:0px;
}
.ui-button-text {
   font-size:13px;
}
```

Comment: thanks that works almost as I wanted with a bit more tweaking it will be a charm. (cause it messes some other elements in the form but iam going to add some classes and adjust it)